# How to auto load textview on a list view and strikethrough some of the textview

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, reload, strikethrough

I am making a todo app. I made a shared preference to save the data to internal storage an an arryadapter to manage my data. Everything works well. I added a strikethrough functionality and it works, but when I exit and reopen the app the strikethrough is gone and I don't know how to restrike through the todos in my listview.
I can populate my listview with the data I extracted from my shared preferences. It shows but it does not strikethrough.
When I tried to access listview getchild, I get a null exception

Comment: To receive help from StackOverflow community make sure you follow [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines and that your question presents [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are checking the task, save its check status in the shared preference depends on check status you can perform strikethrough